# line through vaadin row

Tags: css, text-decorations

I want to make a row in the table to look like a crossed out.
I tried using `text-decoration` but it affects only text

```css
.v-table-row.v-table-row-highlight-red,
.v-table-row-odd.v-table-row-highlight-red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

How to line through through the whole row?

I set code generator for table like this

```js
table.setCellStyleGenerator((source, itemId, propertyId) - > {
  return "highlight-red";
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a normal way but there is a workaround. You can use `box-shadow` to simulate the cross line on a `before` pseudo element.

Like this:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr.deleted td:before {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="deleted">
    <td>
      deleted row
    </td>
     <td>
      deleted row
    </td>
     <td>
      deleted row
    </td>
     <td>
      deleted row
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      regular row
    </td>
     <td>
      regular row
    </td>
     <td>
      regular row
    </td>
     <td>
      regular row
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```